# How to get a submenu in Css & HTML

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

How to get a submenu in Css & HTML like my picture.. I have tried and googled for my requirement but not got any solution 
my requirement is when i mouseouver any menu, it's submenu should be displayed only on the side of the page like my above picture
I may be not googled with any specific keywords that you people may know

Did any one got my idea...stuck with this for last couple of days
[image]

Some of the Code i have tried

HTML

```
div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<ul><li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

#menu {
    width: 550px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #8AD9FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menu li { 
display: inline; 
padding: 20px; 
}

#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00F;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #F90;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: where is your code? i mean what you have done?

Comment: Do you suppose your users will travel their mouse cursor via the red line to the submenu? Seems horrible

Comment: Moving mouse, moving mouse, nearly there....damn hovered off the red bar :(

Comment: Easy to do with Js/JQ and a click. CSS version would be **horrible**.

Comment: @kumartyr: Try this and let know whether it is the expected one or not

Comment: @user1853128 thanks for your reply.. what you have posted really helps me but how to draw a connecting line between the menu selected and its submenu[if the submenu is totally outside the menubar like my image]

Comment: @kumartyr: Updated the answer, use jquery and play with classes, I just added normal answer which can give you an idea

Comment: @kumartyr: I don't think so the requirement is too good, if possible change your requirement....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve..

```
    <ul class="main">
   <li>
      Explore
      <ul class="sub">
         <li>Sub menu 1</li>
         <li>Sub menu 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>More
      <ul class="sub">
         <li>Sub menu 3</li>
         <li>Sub menu 4</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul,li,ol{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
li{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

ul.main li ul.sub li{
    display:none;
}
ul.main li:hover ul.sub li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

ul.sub{
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ck4zn/3/)

Comment: Does not answer the **specific** issue raised by the OP

Comment: @Paulie_D: Actual answer haven't posted

Comment: I have no idea what that means. The OP knows how to create a submenu (at least I assume so) it's the **positioning** that is the issue.

Comment: @kumartyr: Try this and let know whether it is the expected one or not

Comment: Hover the 'More' link and try and use its submenu...See the issue?

Comment: @Paulie_D: I was waiting to get the answer from the questionnaire. I know this issue, I was wondering how he is going to access it.. Lets hope he will understand this issue too

Answer (score 0):

the beginning of the day like so

[Codepen DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fqcrD)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">some text</a></li>
            <li><a href="">some text</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">some textsome textо</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">some textsome text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">some textsome text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">some textsome text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">some textsome text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">some text</a></li>
            <li><a href="">some text</a></li>
            <li><a href="">some text</a></li>
            <li><a href="">some text</a></li>
            <li><a href="">some text</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Does not answer the **specific** issue raised by the OP

Comment: Actual answer haven't posted

Comment: @Alex: what Paulie_D commented is right. It doesn't give solution to my question rather than creating a menu with submenus..Anyway thanks for reply